# dc:creator in xml feed

Tags: xml, google-plus

I have found that some CMS plugins for Google+ authorship add to the rss file dc:creator, which is not valid unless it is defined.Should I keep dc:creator in the XML feed? Is it used for anything?

Comment: See http://www.lowter.com/blogs/2008/2/9/rss-dccreator-author